# Giving value to a dataframe column depending on other dataframe value python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. In the first one I have the customers and a column with a list of every restaurant he/she visited.

```
In [1]: df_customers
Out[1]:

              Document   Restaurants
    0        '000000984  [20504916171, 20504916171, 20499859164]
    1        '000010076  [20505918674, 20505918674, 20505918674]
    2        '000010319  [20253346711, 20524403863, 20508246677]
    3        '000018468  [20253346711, 20538456226, 20505918674]
    4        '000024409  [20553255881, 20553596441, 20553255881]
    5        '000025944  [20492255719, 20600654226]
    6        '000031162  [20600351398, 20408462399, 20499859164]
    7        '000055177  [20524403863, 20524403863]
    8        '000058303  [20600997239, 20524403863, 20600997239]
    9        '000074791  [20517920178, 20517920178, 20517920178]
```

In my other dataframe I have a column with the restaurants and another with a given value for each

```
In [2]: df_rest
Out [2]:

   Restaurant     Points
0  10026575473    1
1  10037003331    1
2  10072208299    1
3  10179698400    2
4  10214262750    1
```

I need to create a column in my customers dataframe with the sum of the points given to each restaurant he/she visited.

I tried something like this:

```
df_customers["Sum"]=df_rest.loc[df_rest["Restaurant"].isin(df_customers["Restaurants"]),"Points"].sum()
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I'm trying not to iterate on my customers dataframe, it takes too long. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Aim not to use lists within Pandas series. Using `list` removes the possibility of vectorised operations. More efficient is to expand your jagged array of restaurant lists into a single dataframe, then map to points via a dictionary and sum.

Here's a minimal example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Document': [1, 2],
                    'Restaurants': [[20504916171, 20504916171, 20499859164],
                                   [20505918674, 20505918674]]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Restaurant': [20504916171, 20504916171, 20499859164,
                                   20505918674, 20505918674],
                    'Points': [1, 2, 1, 3, 2]})

ratmap = df2.set_index('Restaurant')['Points'].to_dict()

df1['score'] = pd.DataFrame(df1['Restaurants'].values.tolist())\
                 .applymap(ratmap.get).fillna(0).sum(1).astype(int)

print(df1)

   Document                              Restaurants  score
0         1  [20504916171, 20504916171, 20499859164]      5
1         2               [20505918674, 20505918674]      4
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first *expand* the `df` into:

```
d = {c: df_customers[c].values.repeat(df_customers.Restaurants.str.len(), axis=0) for c in df_customers.columns}
d['Restaurants'] = [i for sub in df_customers.Restaurants for i in sub]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(d)

    Document    Restaurants
0   000000984   20504916171
1   000000984   20504916171
2   000000984   20499859164
3   000010076   20505918674
4   000010076   20505918674
5   000010076   20505918674
6   000010319   20253346711
7   000010319   20524403863
```

Then `map`

```
df3['Point'] = df3.Restaurants.map(df_rest.set_index('Restaurant').Points).fillna(0)    


    Document    Restaurants Point
0   000000984a  20504916171     1
1   000000984a  20504916171     1
2   000000984a  20499859164     0
3   000010076a  20505918674     0
4   000010076a  20505918674     0
5   000010076a  20505918674     0
```

Then `groupby` document and `sum`

```
df3.groupby('Document').sum() 

            Restaurants Point
Document        
000000984   61509691506 2.0
000010076   61517756022 0.0
000010319   61285997251 0.0
000018468   61297721611 0.0
```

Values are mocked, because no restaurant id from your `df_customers` is present in your `df_rest` in the example you provided.